# Change fancybox title style to "outside" only for videos

Tags: jquery, video, fancybox, title

So I have a gallery of images and one video. I want the images to have the "over" type title and the video to have the "inside" type title. The code below is what I've tried, but the video title remains "over", and clicking on the video thumbnail just causes the fancybox overlay to flash on and off. The video thumbnail otherwise works fine if I remove the fancybox-media definition.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            margin: 10,
            padding: 10,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                },
                media : {}
            }
        });

        $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                }
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/v/EIyixC9NsLI?hd=1&autoplay=1" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="Here is a video."><img class="thumb" src="tn_video.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Does the answer have something to do with `.attr('rel', 'gallery')` ? I don't really understand what that does.

Comment: +1 this is a very good question. It seemed to be possible with previous versions using different selectors but the same `rel` attribute ...but no more.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to create 2 separate fancybox function call, one for `fancybox` `fancybox-media`, because there, they may overlap each other.

Something like this (not tested):

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,

        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'over'
            },
            media : {}
        }
    });
    $(".fancybox-media").fancybox({
        margin: 10,
        padding: 10,

        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            },
            media : {}
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried to pass a function to ```helpers:title:type``` to have something cleaner, but with no success.

Comment: Your solution works for separated links but not for a gallery (which is the initial OP's request). Check http://jsfiddle.net/CzKQA/